# Chrome extension not loading DataTables scripts/CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, datatables

[DataTables configuration example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

I am trying to create a Chrome extension that uses the DataTables style (which uses Bootstrap). It appears to be working locally, but when I package it as an extension, it no longer displays any style.

The manifest file is as follows:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Cookie",
"description": "",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

"permissions": [
"activeTab",
    "tabs",
"cookies",
"history",
"storage",
"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css",
"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js",
"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
"\u003Call_urls\u003E"
]
}
```

My html file uses the following scripts and css:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<!-- refers to a table named 'test' in the body -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#test').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

Does the content scripts field have to be added to the manifest file? If so, how exactly would that look?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there were two main issues:

1. For a Google Chrome extension, a script cannot be run in the HTML file. The solution was to create another javascript file.
2. The scripts (jquery and bootstrap) and css had to be local, so we created another folder and added the files to that.

Comment: It'd be great if you added a link to relevant docs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy